# Symfony 3: How to compress a twig rendered sitemap in a response?

Tags: php, symfony, gzip, sitemap

Say I have a route to return a `sitemap.xml` file for my site. It is generated by rendering a twig file in a controller.

This file is pretty big and I am wondering how to gzip the result into the response. Is this possible in Symfony 3? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

Usually, compression should not be handled by your php code or a framework, but by the http server. You can enable gzip compression in your web server config.

If you're using apache, you can enable mod_deflate for xml files in the configuration. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_deflate.html

You can also create an .htaccess file in the web folder:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
</IfModule>
```

Hope that helps